# Show upsell / related products in search results in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, related-products, up-sells

Looking for some ideas on how to show the up-sell or related products in the search results.

Let's say the customer is looking for `Text123` that can be found in the description of 1 of our products but nowhere else. However this product has 2 up-sell/related products. The goal would be to show all 3 on the catalog search results page.

In order to keep it safe / not so resource heavy:

- This function would run if search results are under a given number (maybe 5-10)
- Infinite loop should be avoided (if they are up-sell/related products both way)
- Also we should avoid showing the same product twice (need to check the items already in the list)

The ideas I had and the reason I hesitated to dig deeper:

1. Showing the up-sell/related products at each product (no space in grid mode)
2. Adding a widget to the bottom (but how could we get the search results data there)
3. Manipulating the search results data (could not find an easy way)
4. Template modification (on the long run I would avoid)

Possibly point 2-3 would be the correct direction, but I got stuck.

If anyone could help with some ideas or code snippets that would be welcomed!

Thank you!